# Implement Dispatch Table in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

I'm looking to implement a dispatch table in TypeScript where different variations of an entity can have different implementations. I'm getting a TypeScript error that I can't seem to resolve. Here is a minimal repro of the issue:

```
type AnimalType = 'DOG' | 'CAT';

type Animal<T> = {
  type: T;
  payload: any;
};

type Hello<T extends AnimalType> = (animal: Animal<T>) => string;

type DispatchTable = {
  [T in AnimalType]: Hello<T>;
};

const dispatchTable: DispatchTable = {
  DOG: (dog: Animal<'DOG'>) => `"woof!" said ${dog.payload.name}`,
  CAT: (cat: Animal<'CAT'>) => `"meow!" said ${cat.payload.name}`,
};

export const hello = <T extends AnimalType>(animal: Animal<T>): string => {
  const hi: Hello<T> = dispatchTable[animal.type]; // Type '"CAT"' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.ts(2322)
  return hi(animal);
};
```

The full error that I'm getting is:

```
Type 'Hello<"DOG"> | Hello<"CAT">' is not assignable to type 'Hello<T>'.
  Type 'Hello<"DOG">' is not assignable to type 'Hello<T>'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.
      Type 'AnimalType' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.
        Type '"CAT"' is not assignable to type '"DOG"'.ts(2322)
```

The type of DispatchTable looks correct, when I hover on it in VSCode I see:

```
type DispatchTable = {
    DOG: Hello<"DOG">;
    CAT: Hello<"CAT">;
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong or is this a limitation of TS? Is there a better pattern to use for implementing different behaviours for different sub types?